# Passing the public partial class Form input to another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, events, namespaces

This may be something that is obvious but i have been searching for months and i have still not find a solution. What I am doing is creating a speech program for my house. So i guess you can say its a Digital House Assistant. I am programming in C# with Visual Studio Community 2013. I have the complete program on one winForm. The thing is it tends to be very lengthy. So i am wanting to break it down into multiple forms such as:

Form1, Form2, Form3, etc., etc.,

However my main form is frmMain. When i go to make another form for example Commands it looks like this.

(Form 1)

public partial class frmMain : Form

(Form 2)

public partial class Commands : Form

*** I would post pictures but i tried and would not let me until i am a reputation 10***

So what i want to do is change both forms to where it says frmMain : Form
When i do that then i can declare my event handlers

_recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler(Default_SpeechRecognized);

and instead of creating a method on Form1 i can generate and declare it on Form2. But when i try that the Initialize Component throws an error. The code below is partial for frmMain (Form1)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TTSEngineLib;
using Alexis.Properties;


namespace Alexis
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {

        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer Alexis = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine startlistening = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
```

If you notice the public partial class frmMain : Form above then the code below it says public frmMain(); This works on a one form and the program runs smooth.

```
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Settings.Default.User.ToString() == String.Empty)
            { Settings.Default.User = userName; Settings.Default.Save(); Alexis.SpeakAsync("Welcome back,  " + Settings.Default.User); }
            else
            { Alexis.Speak("Hello " + Settings.Default.User + ", allow me to load the necessary files,  My system will be up in just a moment."); }
            string[] defaultcommands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Commands.txt"));
            foreach (string command in defaultcommands)
            {
                lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
            }
```

But if i run two forms well in this case it will be about six forms. Would i need to change the public partial class Commands : Form to match the public partial class frmMain : Form   or could i just leave it and build on to it or would i need to start back over from scratch? That is my question. Below is some of the code to get a better view.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TTSEngineLib;
using Alexis.Properties;


namespace Alexis
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {

        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer Alexis = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine startlistening = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
        string Temperature;
        string Condition;
        string Humidity;
        string Windspeed;
        string Town;
        string Distance;
        string Pressure;
        string Windchill;
        string Visibility;
        string Rising;
        string Sunrise;
        string Sunset;
        string State;
        string TFCond;
        string TFHigh;
        string TFLow;
        String[] AlarmAM = { "1:00 AM", "1:01 AM", "1:02 AM", "1:03 AM", "1:04 AM", "1:05 AM", "1:06 AM", "1:07 AM", "1:08 AM", "1:09 AM", "1:10 AM", "1:11 AM", "1:12 AM", "1:13 AM", "1:14 AM", "1:15 AM", "1:16 AM", "1:17 AM", "1:18 AM", "1:19 AM", "1:20 AM", "1:21 AM", "1:22 AM", "1:23 AM", "1:24 AM", "1:25 AM", "1:26 AM", "1:27 AM", "1:28 AM", "1:29 AM", "1:30 AM", "1:31 AM", "1:32 AM", "1:33 AM", "1:34 AM", "1:35 AM", "1:36 AM", "1:37 AM", "1:38 AM", "1:39 AM", "1:40 AM", "1:41 AM", "1:42 AM", "1:43 AM", "1:44 AM", "1:45 AM", "1:46 AM", "1:47 AM", "1:48 AM", "1:49 AM", "1:50 AM", "1:51 AM", "1:52 AM", "1:53 AM", "1:54 AM", "1:55 AM", "1:56 AM", "1:57 AM", "1:58 AM", "1:59 AM", "2:00 AM", "2:01 AM", "2:02 AM", "2:03 AM", "2:04 AM", "2:05 AM", "2:06 AM", "2:07 AM", "2:08 AM", "2:09 AM", "2:10 AM", "2:11 AM", "2:12 AM", "2:13 AM", "2:14 AM", "2:15 AM", "2:16 AM", "2:17 AM", "2:18 AM", "2:19 AM", "2:20 AM", "2:21 AM", "2:22 AM", "2:23 AM", "2:24 AM", "2:25 AM", "2:26 AM", "2:27 AM", "2:28 AM", "2:29 AM", "2:30 AM", "2:31 AM", "2:32 AM", "2:33 AM", "2:34 AM", "2:35 AM", "2:36 AM", "2:37 AM", "2:38 AM", "2:39 AM", "2:40 AM", "2:41 AM", "2:42 AM", "2:43 AM", "2:44 AM", "2:45 AM", "2:46 AM", "2:47 AM", "2:48 AM", "2:49 AM", "2:50 AM", "2:51 AM", "2:52 AM", "2:53 AM", "2:54 AM", "2:55 AM", "2:56 AM", "2:57 AM", "2:58 AM", "2:59 AM", "3:00 AM", "3:01 AM", "3:02 AM", "3:03 AM", "3:04 AM", "3:05 AM", "3:06 AM", "3:07 AM", "3:08 AM", "3:09 AM", "3:10 AM", "3:11 AM", "3:12 AM", "3:13 AM", "3:14 AM", "3:15 AM", "3:16 AM", "3:17 AM", "3:18 AM", "3:19 AM", "3:20 AM", "3:21 AM", "3:22 AM", "3:23 AM", "3:24 AM", "3:25 AM", "3:26 AM", "3:27 AM", "3:28 AM", "3:29 AM", "3:30 AM", "3:31 AM", "3:32 AM", "3:33 AM", "3:34 AM", "3:35 AM", "3:36 AM", "3:37 AM", "3:38 AM", "3:39 AM", "3:40 AM", "3:41 AM", "3:42 AM", "3:43 AM", "3:44 AM", "3:45 AM", "3:46 AM", "3:47 AM", "3:48 AM", "3:49 AM", "3:50 AM", "3:51 AM", "3:52 AM", "3:53 AM", "3:54 AM", "3:55 AM", "3:56 AM", "3:57 AM", "3:58 AM", "3:59 AM", "4:00 AM", "4:01 AM", "4:02 AM", "4:03 AM", "4:04 AM", "4:05 AM", "4:06 AM", "4:07 AM", "4:08 AM", "4:09 AM", "4:10 AM", "4:11 AM", "4:12 AM", "4:13 AM", "4:14 AM", "4:15 AM", "4:16 AM", "4:17 AM", "4:18 AM", "4:19 AM", "4:20 AM", "4:21 AM", "4:22 AM", "4:23 AM", "4:24 AM", "4:25 AM", "4:26 AM", "4:27 AM", "4:28 AM", "4:29 AM", "4:30 AM", "4:31 AM", "4:32 AM", "4:33 AM", "4:34 AM", "4:35 AM", "4:36 AM", "4:37 AM", "4:38 AM", "4:39 AM", "4:40 AM", "4:41 AM", "4:42 AM", "4:43 AM", "4:44 AM", "4:45 AM", "4:46 AM", "4:47 AM", "4:48 AM", "4:49 AM", "4:50 AM", "4:51 AM", "4:52 AM", "4:53 AM", "4:54 AM", "4:55 AM", "4:56 AM", "4:57 AM", "4:58 AM", "4:59 AM", "5:00 AM", "5:01 AM", "5:02 AM", "5:03 AM", "5:04 AM", "5:05 AM", "5:06 AM", "5:07 AM", "5:08 AM", "5:09 AM", "5:10 AM", "5:11 AM", "5:12 AM", "5:13 AM", "5:14 AM", "5:15 AM", "5:16 AM", "5:17 AM", "5:18 AM", "5:19 AM", "5:20 AM", "5:21 AM", "5:22 AM", "5:23 AM", "5:24 AM", "5:25 AM", "5:26 AM", "5:27 AM", "5:28 AM", "5:29 AM", "5:30 AM", "5:31 AM", "5:32 AM", "5:33 AM", "5:34 AM", "5:35 AM", "5:36 AM", "5:37 AM", "5:38 AM", "5:39 AM", "5:40 AM", "5:41 AM", "5:42 AM", "5:43 AM", "5:44 AM", "5:45 AM", "5:46 AM", "5:47 AM", "5:48 AM", "5:49 AM", "5:50 AM", "5:51 AM", "5:52 AM", "5:53 AM", "5:54 AM", "5:55 AM", "5:56 AM", "5:57 AM", "5:58 AM", "5:59 AM", "6:00 AM", "6:01 AM", "6:02 AM", "6:03 AM", "6:04 AM", "6:05 AM", "6:06 AM", "6:07 AM", "6:08 AM", "6:09 AM", "6:10 AM", "6:11 AM", "6:12 AM", "6:13 AM", "6:14 AM", "6:15 AM", "6:16 AM", "6:17 AM", "6:18 AM", "6:19 AM", "6:20 AM", "6:21 AM", "6:22 AM", "6:23 AM", "6:24 AM", "6:25 AM", "6:26 AM", "6:27 AM", "6:28 AM", "6:29 AM", "6:30 AM", "6:31 AM", "6:32 AM", "6:33 AM", "6:34 AM", "6:35 AM", "6:36 AM", "6:37 AM", "6:38 AM", "6:39 AM", "6:40 AM", "6:41 AM", "6:42 AM", "6:43 AM", "6:44 AM", "6:45 AM", "6:46 AM", "6:47 AM", "6:48 AM", "6:49 AM", "6:50 AM", "6:51 AM", "6:52 AM", "6:53 AM", "6:54 AM", "6:55 AM", "6:56 AM", "6:57 AM", "6:58 AM", "6:59 AM", "7:00 AM", "7:01 AM", "7:02 AM", "7:03 AM", "7:04 AM", "7:05 AM", "7:06 AM", "7:07 AM", "7:08 AM", "7:09 AM", "7:10 AM", "7:11 AM", "7:12 AM", "7:13 AM", "7:14 AM", "7:15 AM", "7:16 AM", "7:17 AM", "7:18 AM", "7:19 AM", "7:20 AM", "7:21 AM", "7:22 AM", "7:23 AM", "7:24 AM", "7:25 AM", "7:26 AM", "7:27 AM", "7:28 AM", "7:29 AM", "7:30 AM", "7:31 AM", "7:32 AM", "7:33 AM", "7:34 AM", "7:35 AM", "7:36 AM", "7:37 AM", "7:38 AM", "7:39 AM", "7:40 AM", "7:41 AM", "7:42 AM", "7:43 AM", "7:44 AM", "7:45 AM", "7:46 AM", "7:47 AM", "7:48 AM", "7:49 AM", "7:50 AM", "7:51 AM", "7:52 AM", "7:53 AM", "7:54 AM", "7:55 AM", "7:56 AM", "7:57 AM", "7:58 AM", "7:59 AM", "8:00 AM", "8:01 AM", "8:02 AM", "8:03 AM", "8:04 AM", "8:05 AM", "8:06 AM", "8:07 AM", "8:08 AM", "8:09 AM", "8:10 AM", "8:11 AM", "8:12 AM", "8:13 AM", "8:14 AM", "8:15 AM", "8:16 AM", "8:17 AM", "8:18 AM", "8:19 AM", "8:20 AM", "8:21 AM", "8:22 AM", "8:23 AM", "8:24 AM", "8:25 AM", "8:26 AM", "8:27 AM", "8:28 AM", "8:29 AM", "8:30 AM", "8:31 AM", "8:32 AM", "8:33 AM", "8:34 AM", "8:35 AM", "8:36 AM", "8:37 AM", "8:38 AM", "8:39 AM", "8:40 AM", "8:41 AM", "8:42 AM", "8:43 AM", "8:44 AM", "8:45 AM", "8:46 AM", "8:47 AM", "8:48 AM", "8:49 AM", "8:50 AM", "8:51 AM", "8:52 AM", "8:53 AM", "8:54 AM", "8:55 AM", "8:56 AM", "8:57 AM", "8:58 AM", "8:59 AM", "9:00 AM", "9:01 AM", "9:02 AM", "9:03 AM", "9:04 AM", "9:05 AM", "9:06 AM", "9:07 AM", "9:08 AM", "9:09 AM", "9:10 AM", "9:11 AM", "9:12 AM", "9:13 AM", "9:14 AM", "9:15 AM", "9:16 AM", "9:17 AM", "9:18 AM", "9:19 AM", "9:20 AM", "9:21 AM", "9:22 AM", "9:23 AM", "9:24 AM", "9:25 AM", "9:26 AM", "9:27 AM", "9:28 AM", "9:29 AM", "9:30 AM", "9:31 AM", "9:32 AM", "9:33 AM", "9:34 AM", "9:35 AM", "9:36 AM", "9:37 AM", "9:38 AM", "9:39 AM", "9:40 AM", "9:41 AM", "9:42 AM", "9:43 AM", "9:44 AM", "9:45 AM", "9:46 AM", "9:47 AM", "9:48 AM", "9:49 AM", "9:50 AM", "9:51 AM", "9:52 AM", "9:53 AM", "9:54 AM", "9:55 AM", "9:56 AM", "9:57 AM", "9:58 AM", "9:59 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:01 AM", "10:02 AM", "10:03 AM", "10:04 AM", "10:05 AM", "10:06 AM", "10:07 AM", "10:08 AM", "10:09 AM", "10:10 AM", "10:11 AM", "10:12 AM", "10:13 AM", "10:14 AM", "10:15 AM", "10:16 AM", "10:17 AM", "10:18 AM", "10:19 AM", "10:20 AM", "10:21 AM", "10:22 AM", "10:23 AM", "10:24 AM", "10:25 AM", "10:26 AM", "10:27 AM", "10:28 AM", "10:29 AM", "10:30 AM", "10:31 AM", "10:32 AM", "10:33 AM", "10:34 AM", "10:35 AM", "10:36 AM", "10:37 AM", "10:38 AM", "10:39 AM", "10:40 AM", "10:41 AM", "10:42 AM", "10:43 AM", "10:44 AM", "10:45 AM", "10:46 AM", "10:47 AM", "10:48 AM", "10:49 AM", "10:50 AM", "10:51 AM", "10:52 AM", "10:53 AM", "10:54 AM", "10:55 AM", "10:56 AM", "10:57 AM", "10:58 AM", "10:59 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:01 AM", "11:02 AM", "11:03 AM", "11:04 AM", "11:05 AM", "11:06 AM", "11:07 AM", "11:08 AM", "11:09 AM", "11:10 AM", "11:11 AM", "11:12 AM", "11:13 AM", "11:14 AM", "11:15 AM", "11:16 AM", "11:17 AM", "11:18 AM", "11:19 AM", "11:20 AM", "11:21 AM", "11:22 AM", "11:23 AM", "11:24 AM", "11:25 AM", "11:26 AM", "11:27 AM", "11:28 AM", "11:29 AM", "11:30 AM", "11:31 AM", "11:32 AM", "11:33 AM", "11:34 AM", "11:35 AM", "11:36 AM", "11:37 AM", "11:38 AM", "11:39 AM", "11:40 AM", "11:41 AM", "11:42 AM", "11:43 AM", "11:44 AM", "11:45 AM", "11:46 AM", "11:47 AM", "11:48 AM", "11:49 AM", "11:50 AM", "11:51 AM", "11:52 AM", "11:53 AM", "11:54 AM", "11:55 AM", "11:56 AM", "11:57 AM", "11:58 AM", "11:59 AM", "12:00 AM", "12:01 AM", "12:02 AM", "12:03 AM", "12:04 AM", "12:05 AM", "12:06 AM", "12:07 AM", "12:08 AM", "12:09 AM", "12:10 AM", "12:11 AM", "12:12 AM", "12:13 AM", "12:14 AM", "12:15 AM", "12:16 AM", "12:17 AM", "12:18 AM", "12:19 AM", "12:20 AM", "12:21 AM", "12:22 AM", "12:23 AM", "12:24 AM", "12:25 AM", "12:26 AM", "12:27 AM", "12:28 AM", "12:29 AM", "12:30 AM", "12:31 AM", "12:32 AM", "12:33 AM", "12:34 AM", "12:35 AM", "12:36 AM", "12:37 AM", "12:38 AM", "12:39 AM", "12:40 AM", "12:41 AM", "12:42 AM", "12:43 AM", "12:44 AM", "12:45 AM", "12:46 AM", "12:47 AM", "12:48 AM", "12:49 AM", "12:50 AM", "12:51 AM", "12:52 AM", "12:53 AM", "12:54 AM", "12:55 AM", "12:56 AM", "12:57 AM", "12:58 AM", "12:59 AM" };
        String[] AlarmPM = { "1:00 PM", "1:01 PM", "1:02 PM", "1:03 PM", "1:04 PM", "1:05 PM", "1:06 PM", "1:07 PM", "1:08 PM", "1:09 PM", "1:10 PM", "1:11 PM", "1:12 PM", "1:13 PM", "1:14 PM", "1:15 PM", "1:16 PM", "1:17 PM", "1:18 PM", "1:19 PM", "1:20 PM", "1:21 PM", "1:22 PM", "1:23 PM", "1:24 PM", "1:25 PM", "1:26 PM", "1:27 PM", "1:28 PM", "1:29 PM", "1:30 PM", "1:31 PM", "1:32 PM", "1:33 PM", "1:34 PM", "1:35 PM", "1:36 PM", "1:37 PM", "1:38 PM", "1:39 PM", "1:40 PM", "1:41 PM", "1:42 PM", "1:43 PM", "1:44 PM", "1:45 PM", "1:46 PM", "1:47 PM", "1:48 PM", "1:49 PM", "1:50 PM", "1:51 PM", "1:52 PM", "1:53 PM", "1:54 PM", "1:55 PM", "1:56 PM", "1:57 PM", "1:58 PM", "1:59 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:01 PM", "2:02 PM", "2:03 PM", "2:04 PM", "2:05 PM", "2:06 PM", "2:07 PM", "2:08 PM", "2:09 PM", "2:10 PM", "2:11 PM", "2:12 PM", "2:13 PM", "2:14 PM", "2:15 PM", "2:16 PM", "2:17 PM", "2:18 PM", "2:19 PM", "2:20 PM", "2:21 PM", "2:22 PM", "2:23 PM", "2:24 PM", "2:25 PM", "2:26 PM", "2:27 PM", "2:28 PM", "2:29 PM", "2:30 PM", "2:31 PM", "2:32 PM", "2:33 PM", "2:34 PM", "2:35 PM", "2:36 PM", "2:37 PM", "2:38 PM", "2:39 PM", "2:40 PM", "2:41 PM", "2:42 PM", "2:43 PM", "2:44 PM", "2:45 PM", "2:46 PM", "2:47 PM", "2:48 PM", "2:49 PM", "2:50 PM", "2:51 PM", "2:52 PM", "2:53 PM", "2:54 PM", "2:55 PM", "2:56 PM", "2:57 PM", "2:58 PM", "2:59 PM", "3:00 PM", "3:01 PM", "3:02 PM", "3:03 PM", "3:04 PM", "3:05 PM", "3:06 PM", "3:07 PM", "3:08 PM", "3:09 PM", "3:10 PM", "3:11 PM", "3:12 PM", "3:13 PM", "3:14 PM", "3:15 PM", "3:16 PM", "3:17 PM", "3:18 PM", "3:19 PM", "3:20 PM", "3:21 PM", "3:22 PM", "3:23 PM", "3:24 PM", "3:25 PM", "3:26 PM", "3:27 PM", "3:28 PM", "3:29 PM", "3:30 PM", "3:31 PM", "3:32 PM", "3:33 PM", "3:34 PM", "3:35 PM", "3:36 PM", "3:37 PM", "3:38 PM", "3:39 PM", "3:40 PM", "3:41 PM", "3:42 PM", "3:43 PM", "3:44 PM", "3:45 PM", "3:46 PM", "3:47 PM", "3:48 PM", "3:49 PM", "3:50 PM", "3:51 PM", "3:52 PM", "3:53 PM", "3:54 PM", "3:55 PM", "3:56 PM", "3:57 PM", "3:58 PM", "3:59 PM", "4:00 PM", "4:01 PM", "4:02 PM", "4:03 PM", "4:04 PM", "4:05 PM", "4:06 PM", "4:07 PM", "4:08 PM", "4:09 PM", "4:10 PM", "4:11 PM", "4:12 PM", "4:13 PM", "4:14 PM", "4:15 PM", "4:16 PM", "4:17 PM", "4:18 PM", "4:19 PM", "4:20 PM", "4:21 PM", "4:22 PM", "4:23 PM", "4:24 PM", "4:25 PM", "4:26 PM", "4:27 PM", "4:28 PM", "4:29 PM", "4:30 PM", "4:31 PM", "4:32 PM", "4:33 PM", "4:34 PM", "4:35 PM", "4:36 PM", "4:37 PM", "4:38 PM", "4:39 PM", "4:40 PM", "4:41 PM", "4:42 PM", "4:43 PM", "4:44 PM", "4:45 PM", "4:46 PM", "4:47 PM", "4:48 PM", "4:49 PM", "4:50 PM", "4:51 PM", "4:52 PM", "4:53 PM", "4:54 PM", "4:55 PM", "4:56 PM", "4:57 PM", "4:58 PM", "4:59 PM", "5:00 PM", "5:01 PM", "5:02 PM", "5:03 PM", "5:04 PM", "5:05 PM", "5:06 PM", "5:07 PM", "5:08 PM", "5:09 PM", "5:10 PM", "5:11 PM", "5:12 PM", "5:13 PM", "5:14 PM", "5:15 PM", "5:16 PM", "5:17 PM", "5:18 PM", "5:19 PM", "5:20 PM", "5:21 PM", "5:22 PM", "5:23 PM", "5:24 PM", "5:25 PM", "5:26 PM", "5:27 PM", "5:28 PM", "5:29 PM", "5:30 PM", "5:31 PM", "5:32 PM", "5:33 PM", "5:34 PM", "5:35 PM", "5:36 PM", "5:37 PM", "5:38 PM", "5:39 PM", "5:40 PM", "5:41 PM", "5:42 PM", "5:43 PM", "5:44 PM", "5:45 PM", "5:46 PM", "5:47 PM", "5:48 PM", "5:49 PM", "5:50 PM", "5:51 PM", "5:52 PM", "5:53 PM", "5:54 PM", "5:55 PM", "5:56 PM", "5:57 PM", "5:58 PM", "5:59 PM", "6:00 PM", "6:01 PM", "6:02 PM", "6:03 PM", "6:04 PM", "6:05 PM", "6:06 PM", "6:07 PM", "6:08 PM", "6:09 PM", "6:10 PM", "6:11 PM", "6:12 PM", "6:13 PM", "6:14 PM", "6:15 PM", "6:16 PM", "6:17 PM", "6:18 PM", "6:19 PM", "6:20 PM", "6:21 PM", "6:22 PM", "6:23 PM", "6:24 PM", "6:25 PM", "6:26 PM", "6:27 PM", "6:28 PM", "6:29 PM", "6:30 PM", "6:31 PM", "6:32 PM", "6:33 PM", "6:34 PM", "6:35 PM", "6:36 PM", "6:37 PM", "6:38 PM", "6:39 PM", "6:40 PM", "6:41 PM", "6:42 PM", "6:43 PM", "6:44 PM", "6:45 PM", "6:46 PM", "6:47 PM", "6:48 PM", "6:49 PM", "6:50 PM", "6:51 PM", "6:52 PM", "6:53 PM", "6:54 PM", "6:55 PM", "6:56 PM", "6:57 PM", "6:58 PM", "6:59 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:01 PM", "7:02 PM", "7:03 PM", "7:04 PM", "7:05 PM", "7:06 PM", "7:07 PM", "7:08 PM", "7:09 PM", "7:10 PM", "7:11 PM", "7:12 PM", "7:13 PM", "7:14 PM", "7:15 PM", "7:16 PM", "7:17 PM", "7:18 PM", "7:19 PM", "7:20 PM", "7:21 PM", "7:22 PM", "7:23 PM", "7:24 PM", "7:25 PM", "7:26 PM", "7:27 PM", "7:28 PM", "7:29 PM", "7:30 PM", "7:31 PM", "7:32 PM", "7:33 PM", "7:34 PM", "7:35 PM", "7:36 PM", "7:37 PM", "7:38 PM", "7:39 PM", "7:40 PM", "7:41 PM", "7:42 PM", "7:43 PM", "7:44 PM", "7:45 PM", "7:46 PM", "7:47 PM", "7:48 PM", "7:49 PM", "7:50 PM", "7:51 PM", "7:52 PM", "7:53 PM", "7:54 PM", "7:55 PM", "7:56 PM", "7:57 PM", "7:58 PM", "7:59 PM", "8:00 PM", "8:01 PM", "8:02 PM", "8:03 PM", "8:04 PM", "8:05 PM", "8:06 PM", "8:07 PM", "8:08 PM", "8:09 PM", "8:10 PM", "8:11 PM", "8:12 PM", "8:13 PM", "8:14 PM", "8:15 PM", "8:16 PM", "8:17 PM", "8:18 PM", "8:19 PM", "8:20 PM", "8:21 PM", "8:22 PM", "8:23 PM", "8:24 PM", "8:25 PM", "8:26 PM", "8:27 PM", "8:28 PM", "8:29 PM", "8:30 PM", "8:31 PM", "8:32 PM", "8:33 PM", "8:34 PM", "8:35 PM", "8:36 PM", "8:37 PM", "8:38 PM", "8:39 PM", "8:40 PM", "8:41 PM", "8:42 PM", "8:43 PM", "8:44 PM", "8:45 PM", "8:46 PM", "8:47 PM", "8:48 PM", "8:49 PM", "8:50 PM", "8:51 PM", "8:52 PM", "8:53 PM", "8:54 PM", "8:55 PM", "8:56 PM", "8:57 PM", "8:58 PM", "8:59 PM", "9:00 PM", "9:01 PM", "9:02 PM", "9:03 PM", "9:04 PM", "9:05 PM", "9:06 PM", "9:07 PM", "9:08 PM", "9:09 PM", "9:10 PM", "9:11 PM", "9:12 PM", "9:13 PM", "9:14 PM", "9:15 PM", "9:16 PM", "9:17 PM", "9:18 PM", "9:19 PM", "9:20 PM", "9:21 PM", "9:22 PM", "9:23 PM", "9:24 PM", "9:25 PM", "9:26 PM", "9:27 PM", "9:28 PM", "9:29 PM", "9:30 PM", "9:31 PM", "9:32 PM", "9:33 PM", "9:34 PM", "9:35 PM", "9:36 PM", "9:37 PM", "9:38 PM", "9:39 PM", "9:40 PM", "9:41 PM", "9:42 PM", "9:43 PM", "9:44 PM", "9:45 PM", "9:46 PM", "9:47 PM", "9:48 PM", "9:49 PM", "9:50 PM", "9:51 PM", "9:52 PM", "9:53 PM", "9:54 PM", "9:55 PM", "9:56 PM", "9:57 PM", "9:58 PM", "9:59 PM", "10:00 PM", "10:01 PM", "10:02 PM", "10:03 PM", "10:04 PM", "10:05 PM", "10:06 PM", "10:07 PM", "10:08 PM", "10:09 PM", "10:10 PM", "10:11 PM", "10:12 PM", "10:13 PM", "10:14 PM", "10:15 PM", "10:16 PM", "10:17 PM", "10:18 PM", "10:19 PM", "10:20 PM", "10:21 PM", "10:22 PM", "10:23 PM", "10:24 PM", "10:25 PM", "10:26 PM", "10:27 PM", "10:28 PM", "10:29 PM", "10:30 PM", "10:31 PM", "10:32 PM", "10:33 PM", "10:34 PM", "10:35 PM", "10:36 PM", "10:37 PM", "10:38 PM", "10:39 PM", "10:40 PM", "10:41 PM", "10:42 PM", "10:43 PM", "10:44 PM", "10:45 PM", "10:46 PM", "10:47 PM", "10:48 PM", "10:49 PM", "10:50 PM", "10:51 PM", "10:52 PM", "10:53 PM", "10:54 PM", "10:55 PM", "10:56 PM", "10:57 PM", "10:58 PM", "10:59 PM", "11:00 PM", "11:01 PM", "11:02 PM", "11:03 PM", "11:04 PM", "11:05 PM", "11:06 PM", "11:07 PM", "11:08 PM", "11:09 PM", "11:10 PM", "11:11 PM", "11:12 PM", "11:13 PM", "11:14 PM", "11:15 PM", "11:16 PM", "11:17 PM", "11:18 PM", "11:19 PM", "11:20 PM", "11:21 PM", "11:22 PM", "11:23 PM", "11:24 PM", "11:25 PM", "11:26 PM", "11:27 PM", "11:28 PM", "11:29 PM", "11:30 PM", "11:31 PM", "11:32 PM", "11:33 PM", "11:34 PM", "11:35 PM", "11:36 PM", "11:37 PM", "11:38 PM", "11:39 PM", "11:40 PM", "11:41 PM", "11:42 PM", "11:43 PM", "11:44 PM", "11:45 PM", "11:46 PM", "11:47 PM", "11:48 PM", "11:49 PM", "11:50 PM", "11:51 PM", "11:52 PM", "11:53 PM", "11:54 PM", "11:55 PM", "11:56 PM", "11:57 PM", "11:58 PM", "11:59 PM", "12:00 PM", "12:01 PM", "12:02 PM", "12:03 PM", "12:04 PM", "12:05 PM", "12:06 PM", "12:07 PM", "12:08 PM", "12:09 PM", "12:10 PM", "12:11 PM", "12:12 PM", "12:13 PM", "12:14 PM", "12:15 PM", "12:16 PM", "12:17 PM", "12:18 PM", "12:19 PM", "12:20 PM", "12:21 PM", "12:22 PM", "12:23 PM", "12:24 PM", "12:25 PM", "12:26 PM", "12:27 PM", "12:28 PM", "12:29 PM", "12:30 PM", "12:31 PM", "12:32 PM", "12:33 PM", "12:34 PM", "12:35 PM", "12:36 PM", "12:37 PM", "12:38 PM", "12:39 PM", "12:40 PM", "12:41 PM", "12:42 PM", "12:43 PM", "12:44 PM", "12:45 PM", "12:46 PM", "12:47 PM", "12:48 PM", "12:49 PM", "12:50 PM", "12:51 PM", "12:52 PM", "12:53 PM", "12:54 PM", "12:55 PM", "12:56 PM", "12:57 PM", "12:58 PM", "12:59 PM" };
        String AlarmTime;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public static List<string> MsgList = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> MsgLink = new List<string>();
        int EmailNum = 0;
        Grammar shellcommandgrammar;
        Grammar webcommandgrammar, socialcommandgrammar;
        String[] ArrayShellCommands;
        String[] ArrayShellResponse;
        String[] ArrayShellLocation;
        String[] ArrayWebCommands;
        String[] ArrayWebResponse;
        String[] ArrayWebURL;
        String[] ArraySocialCommands;
        String[] ArraySocialResponse;
        string scpath;
        string srpath;
        string slpath;
        string webcpath;
        string webrpath;
        string weblpath;
        string socpath;
        string sorpath;
        public static String userName = Environment.UserName;
        public static String QEvent;
        int i = 0;
        int recTimeOut = 0;
        StreamWriter sw;
        StreamReader sr;
        string BPressure;
        string Country;
        string Speed;
        string Degrees;



        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Settings.Default.User.ToString() == String.Empty)
            { Settings.Default.User = userName; Settings.Default.Save(); Alexis.SpeakAsync("Welcome back,  " + Settings.Default.User); }
            else
            { Alexis.Speak("Hello " + Settings.Default.User + ", allow me to load the necessary files,  My system will be up in just a moment."); }
            string[] defaultcommands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Commands.txt"));
            foreach (string command in defaultcommands)
            {
                lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
            }


            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands");
            Settings.Default.ShellC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Commands.txt";
            Settings.Default.ShellR = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Response.txt";
            Settings.Default.ShellL = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Location.txt";
            Settings.Default.WebC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Web Commands.txt";
            Settings.Default.WebR = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Web Response.txt";
            Settings.Default.WebL = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Web URL.txt";
            Settings.Default.SocC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Social Commands.txt";
            Settings.Default.SocR = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Social Response.txt";
            Settings.Default.Save();

            scpath = Settings.Default.ShellC;
            srpath = Settings.Default.ShellR;
            slpath = Settings.Default.ShellL;
            webcpath = Settings.Default.WebC;
            webrpath = Settings.Default.WebR;
            weblpath = Settings.Default.WebL;
            socpath = Settings.Default.SocC;
            sorpath = Settings.Default.SocR;


            if (!File.Exists(scpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(scpath); sw.Write("My Documents"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(srpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(srpath); sw.Write("Right away"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(slpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(slpath); sw.Write(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(webcpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(webcpath); sw.Write("Open Google"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(webrpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(webrpath); sw.Write("Very well"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(weblpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(weblpath); sw.Write("http://www.google.com"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(socpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(socpath); sw.Write("How are you"); sw.Close(); }
            if (!File.Exists(sorpath))
            { sw = File.CreateText(sorpath); sw.Write("I'm doing well thanks for asking"); sw.Close(); }



            ArrayShellCommands = File.ReadAllLines(scpath);
            ArrayShellResponse = File.ReadAllLines(srpath);
            ArrayShellLocation = File.ReadAllLines(slpath);
            ArrayWebCommands = File.ReadAllLines(webcpath);
            ArrayWebResponse = File.ReadAllLines(webrpath);
            ArrayWebURL = File.ReadAllLines(weblpath);
            ArraySocialCommands = File.ReadAllLines(socpath);
            ArraySocialResponse = File.ReadAllLines(sorpath);


            try
            { shellcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArrayShellCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(shellcommandgrammar); }
            catch
            { Alexis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your computer commands, possibly a blank line. Computer commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
            try
            { webcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArrayWebCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(webcommandgrammar); }
            catch
            { Alexis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your web commands, possibly a blank line. Web commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
            try
            { socialcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArraySocialCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(socialcommandgrammar); }
            catch
            { Alexis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your social commands, possibly a blank line. Social commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }



        }




              private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Commands.txt")))));
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Shell_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Social_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Web_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Default_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(AlarmClock_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(AlarmAM))));
            _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(AlarmPM))));
            _recognizer.SpeechDetected += new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechDetected);
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            startlistening.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            startlistening.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("alexis"))));
            startlistening.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(startlistening_SpeechRecognized);
```

There is over 7,000 lines of code so i only added about a hundred lines or so. But i want to organize this into multiple forms. Having just one form with thousands of lines gets frustrating after awhile. So then the Question as before how do i change the forms to have the same public partial class frmMain : Form   once i get this i can pass all of the events no problem.

Any Ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Even the hundreds of lines of code you posted is too much. Please present your code in the form of [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do _not_ post your real-world code for the sake of the example; instead, provide a simple example that clearly illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: First of all, does everything have to be a form? I'd imagine not. How many actual forms (ie: windows) do you really need for a program like this?

I'm just not at all sure what it is you're asking so maybe I'm not understanding the problem you're having correctly but to me it seems like you're running into some design issues and not into coding issues.

Comment: There is only going to be maybe 4 to 6 forms. However when i pass the events in using the Systems.Speech and create the events such as the Default speech EventArgs then i can create a method on another form. Its that when i do that it throws an error. for example on the forms.

Comment: I want to have the FrmMain which has all the events and methods. Then say on Commands : Form i can call the speech recognition for basic commands and then on my RSSFeed i can simply go on the Commands for and get the RSSFeeds by using RSSFeed.GetWeather and it would pull the XML values. SO i am Saying a voice command and it passes through all the forms and executes the commands. This works when i have it on a one form. However the RSSFeed does not have to be in a form itself but the coding needs to pass from the class form when i say the command that is on the Commands : Form.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is still a little bit unclear despite the code you've posted. But I *think* I understand what you're saying. Hopefully this will help.

Having partial classes means you can spread the code for your class over several files - it's still compiled as one class. For it all to be compiled into one class all the partial files need to have the [same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4504288/109702). You can have multiple classes called `frmMain` provided they have different namespaces, as the namespace forms part of the name.

It seems like you need [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+winforms+inheritance), so that you can provide some base functionality that all forms have, and they can selectively override it? Like this rough example:

```
protected partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    var _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += FrmLoaded;
    }

    protected virtual void FrmLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Shell_SpeechRecognized);

    }

    protected virtual void Shell_SpeechRecognized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //common code for handling this event
    }
}

public class frmMain : BaseForm
{
    //override the stuff you need
}
```

Comment: So how would i go about using the Inheritance. I have changed the name to frmMain in the class view and even changed the settings from Font to Inherit. However I can still not get it to work

Comment: @IanMassey check my edit, it's a rough example but should set you on your way.

Comment: Ok i have never seen protected virtual void before. Let me explain a little further. In my program i can say a voice command, I want to add commands. Then my window comes up so you can customize the commands you want. Once you save that. Then on another form with no window it has the default commands. on the frmMain form it has all the Speech events. So when you say a command then it will detect the speech and hear the command via frmMain  then it will execute the command on one of the other forms. It works perfectly with one form but i want to not have my UI so jumbled

Comment: I am going to make a quick video and load it up to youtube so so you can see what i am talking about

Comment: From what you've described, you need all the event handlers in frmMain, then the event handler code pops up the appropriate form for you to enter details, then when the details are entered they are also passed back to frmMain to use it, and all commands are executed in frmMain. There are other more advanced ways to do this using delegates or dynamically loaded/compiled code, but that's beyond the scope of a single answer.

Comment: Exactly! I can run my program on the one form. However, i am always adding to it. So instead of searching for where to put and if the events and handlers are there and not have any problems then i can just put my RSSFeeds in the Feeds class, then update them on another form. So basically there is two Forms that show everything else is done in the background between 6 forms. The forms are RSSFeed, Commands, System Managment, Music, then the two with windows is the Commands list with opening video then the customize or add your own commands.

Comment: so how would i go about doing that? Every time i try to pass event handler through another form i get an error.  here is the break down  frmMain = event handlers(window that shows list box),  Commands = default coded commands(no window, but commands show in the listbox on frmMain), RSSFeed(class, no window), Customize commands = custom commands(window shows with input fields, also shows in list box on frmMain), System Management = statistics of homenetwork(computer generated voice only, no windows) these are the main ones. how would i pass the event handlers between them.

Comment: And remember this all done by voice. the only buttons that will be on there is for the customization of commands. So i need to figure out how to do this using only System.Speech. Eventually i will add Dictation in there in the near weeks coming up

Comment: @IanMassey *"Every time i try to pass event handler through another form i get an error."* You don't pass event handlers around - an event handler executes it's own code, part of that can be to open another form and invoke code in it. If you have multiple forms open each with an event handler hooked up then they could all potentially respond to the same event independently of each other. This is all getting way too big and complex for one question, we should also avoid long comment chains like this one.

Comment: You need to carefully think and design this up front before writing code, rather than trying to fit existing badly designed code to do something. There's nothing wrong with going back to the drawing board and starting again, then copy paste the code you can reuse into the new project.